# Blog open in new Tab

Tags: posts, wp-admin

I'v got the problem, that I want to open a post in a new Tab (lik target="_blank"). How can I say wordpress that it should open me the post in a new Tab when I am clicking on the button or preview text of the post.

I'am useing the standard wordpress blog.

Thank you

Comment: Preview already opens in new tab in standard wp, or you have custom setup ?

Comment: I do not have a custom setup. But if I click on the post container it opens me the post in the same window. I do not want this.

Comment: You have to edit template files to add the target="_blank" to the links that open single post. I assume you want to open them in separate tab when you browse blog page?

Comment: Jes. Correctly whats the default name of this file?